# How does one view a stochastic process as an element of the space of bounded functions?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I can't see how a processes $X=(X_{t})_{t\in T}$ is an element of $\ell^{\infty}(T)$ which is what Van der Vaart writes in the beginning of chapter $18$ in his book on asymptotic statistics. Given that we have observed some $\omega$, sure, then a path is in this space but if not then I don't see how this is something which you would say. I quote

"We are particularly interested in developing the theory(of convergence in distribution) for random functions, or stochastic processes, viewed as elements of the metric space of all bounded functions"

He goes on to keep this perspective a few pages ahead

"Thus, we may concentrate on weak convergence in the space $\ell^{\infty}(T)$"

This leaves me confused, could anyone explain why he formulate himself in this way?

Comment: A path or realization of the process can be an element of $L^\infty(T)$, or $C(T)$, or $L^2(T)$, or any number of things. This author happens to be choosing his paths to be bounded. That's all there is to it at this level.

Comment: @Ian But a procsses is more then 1 path, right? It should be one for each outcome. And when one considers convergence is should atleast be that all paths agree for all outcomes $\omega$

Comment: Yes a (single) process can be thought of as a distribution on paths. So I'd have to see the context to really be sure about what's going on with this. For instance you might ask for weak convergence in $L^\infty(T)$ a.s.

Comment: @Ian to me, when one considers weak convergence of functions one thinks of them as elements $f_{n}:A \rightarrow B$, not as elements of $B$. This is what bothers me, elements of $B$ or $L^{\infty}$ is where the functions which converge weakly takes its values. But maybe im missing some point here which makes thinking of the whole function and not just it values, unnecessary

Comment: To me weak convergence means pointwise convergence when you possibly have made the elements of the sequence act as functions on a space that it they don't act on *a priori*. For example "weak convergence in $L^p$" means pointwise convergence as linear functionals on $L^q$. But I don't have enough context to see where the $\Omega$ dependence comes in for your author.

Comment: @Ian Looking at the definiton of weak convergence makes one think that it mightbe that it is the convergence of the values of the function and not the function per se that of importance, is this what you are saying?

Comment: I'm not really saying anything in particular because I don't think I have enough context. I suspect that as Byron has suggested, your weak convergence means weak convergence of the laws of the processes. These laws are probability measures on $L^\infty(T)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stochastic process $X$ is a function of two variables
$(\omega,t)\mapsto X(\omega,t).$

One way to look at $X$ is that every $t$ gives 
a function $\omega\mapsto X(\omega,t)$, i.e., 
a stochastic process is a family of random variables.

Another way to look at $X$ is that every $\omega$ gives 
a function $t\mapsto X(\omega,t)$, i.e., 
a stochastic process is a random function on $T$.
If $X$ is bounded, then this function belongs to $\ell^\infty(T)$
for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Thus, $X$ is not an element of $\ell^\infty(T)$, it is a mapping
from $\Omega$ to $\ell^\infty(T)$. The distribution of $X$ is a probability 
measure on $\ell^\infty(T)$, and convergence of such random variables
 corresponds to convergence of probability measures on $\ell^\infty(T)$.